# Reinforcement learning in finance

Tags: finance, machine-learning, statistical-finance

In brief, what are some mainstream and recent applications of reinforcement learning in finance that fall outside of the usual scope of agent-based modeling?

Answer (score 3):

Really recommend this book for RL in finance :

- [Dixon et al (2020) *Machine Learning in Finance: From Theory to Practice*](https://www.amazon.in/Machine-Learning-Finance-Theory-Practice/dp/3030410676/ref=nodl_)

He talks about QLBS, q-learning setup for black scholes, RL for investment management and inverse RL for trading.

Answer (score 1):

See Alexandr Honchar's post on portfolio optimization with RL: https://medium.com/swlh/ai-for-portfolio-management-from-markowitz-to-reinforcement-learning-cffedcbba566

Comment: Can you explain how Q-learning portfolios described in your link work? How does RL determine which action for which state, and is this restricted to day-trading